# Tornado Unittest mock yield statements

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, mocking, tornado, tornado-motor

When running Unit tests for a tornado application i keep getting this error:

```
tornado.ioloop.TimeoutError: Operation timed out after 5 seconds
```

here's the test code:

```
class TestMongo(testing.AsyncTestCase):

def setUp(self):
    super().setUp()
@patch('stashboard.checkers.events')
@testing.gen_test()
def test_check(self, event_mock,): # tests for Ok connection status
    event_mock.STATUS_OK = events.STATUS_OK
    event_mock.STATUS_FAIL = events.STATUS_FAIL
    event_mock.save.return_value = Future()
    d = {'path': '/test'}
    test = MongoChecker(d, 1, None)
    yield test.check()
    event_mock.save.assert_called_with({'path': '/test'},
                                 {'status': events.STATUS_OK,
                             'address': '#address#'})
```

and here's the code being tested:

```
class MongoChecker(Checker):
# pings Mongo servers noted in configuration to make sure
# they are still running

def __init__(self, event, frequency, params):
    super().__init__(event, frequency, params)
    self.clients = []
    for server in configuration["mongodb"]:
        host = server["host"]
        port = server["port"]
        address = 'mongodb://{}:{}'.format(host, port)
        client = motor.motor_tornado.MotorClient(
            address)
        # creates client to test connection
        client.address = address
        self.clients.append(client)

@gen.coroutine
def check(self):
    for client in self.clients:
        try:
            yield client.admin.command('ping')
            data= {'address': client.address, 'status': events.STATUS_OK}
        except ConnectionError:
            data = {'address': client.address, 'status': events.STATUS_FAIL}
        yield self.save(data)
```

This is the method that is actually called for the assertion:

```
@gen.coroutine
def save(self, data):
    yield events.save(self.event, data)
```

When I remove the yield statement from `yield self.save(data)` the test works fine. I need to mock a `Future` object to return from `self.save` and also get the actual results from that.

Comment: Is MongoDB running? Can Motor connect to it?

Comment: Yeah, if i were to take the `yield` away from `yield self.save(data)` in `MongoChecker` the test runs fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have patched `stashboard.checkers.events` and set `Future` as return value, so the code:

```
@gen.coroutine
def save(self, data):
    yield events.save(self.event, data)
```

become

```
@gen.coroutine
def save(self, data):
    yield Future()
```

`yield Future` means that Tornado will wait until the given future will be resolved, either by `set_result` or by `set_exception`. In the unit test for safety reasons (and sane) there is a time limit for the each test/suite. Since you haven't set the result, test would last forever, thankfully its timed out.

You could use [`tornado.gen.maybe_future`](http://tornado.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gen.html#tornado.gen.maybe_future) to set the result for coroutine. So the mock setup could look like:

```
@patch('stashboard.checkers.events')
@testing.gen_test()
def test_check(self, event_mock,): # tests for Ok connection status
    event_mock.STATUS_OK = events.STATUS_OK
    event_mock.STATUS_FAIL = events.STATUS_FAIL
    event_mock.save.return_value = tornado.gen.maybe_future('some dummy ret')
    # ...
```